# "Can I talk to you?" vs "Can we talk?"

Tags: emotions

Maybe it's just me, but "Can I talk to you?" (CITTY) feels like a situation where "you" did something wrong, and "I" want to address it.

"Can we talk?" (CWT) feels more like casual conversation, or at least it's less of a concern about "you".

May I have confirmation on this, or is it just me?

[EDIT] Assume this is written on a note, or sent by itself in a message.

Comment: The subtleties of meaning in the two are highly dependent on context and tone of voice.

Comment: @hot-licks Point taken. But, I'm still curious if the context can be taken from these choices of words alone, if it were sent through a message all my itself, like in chat or a text message.

Comment: @dgood1 there's no such thing as a context-free communication.  Even an email from a stranger has context, such as "seeming like spam".

Comment: I guess Hot Licks' comment is the correct answer then. Thank you

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Just to bear out @HotLicks comment about context and voice; if we were going from words alone, I would have the meanings the opposite way round from the OP.

Comment: @Spagirl me too - "Can we talk?" is almost as bad as "We need to talk" for the "uh-oh" factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I knew the name of this phenomenon, but phrases like "Can we talk?" are loaded with ambiguity, because they are **so obviously literally true that we must assume there's a hidden meaning**.

If I was to say to you "Can you play piano?" then the meaning is pretty clear - most people can't, so it's a reasonable question and would be answered on face value, ie whether you're literally capable of playing the piano to some degree.

On the other hand, if you say "Can we talk?", the all of the basic interpretations are **completely obvious**:

"Are we capable of talking?" - yes, most people at least can generate speech.

"Are we allowed to talk?" - yes, of course - we already are, by virtue of you asking me that, and it's not illegal.

etc.

A vital part of comprehension is **guessing the motives of the speaker** - we want to answer the *real* question behind the words, not to just act like a robot and say "Yes, I can form words using my brain and mouth".  In this case, because all of the literal interpretations are so obviously easy to answer, we must assume that the speaker is actually **asking something else, more subtle**.  There are a lot of different things they could be asking:

"Do you have time to talk right now?", "Can we talk without Susan overhearing?", 
"Can we have a serious talk about something instead of the usual chit-chat", "We need to deal with that issue we've both been deliberately avoiding", "I'm going to fire you, and would like to do it in private instead of in front of your colleagues", etc.

We can't avoid this guesswork, which is what makes the question so ambiguous.